# C# My maze generator can't seem to handle blocks with three open sides

Tags: c#, maze, procedural-generation, procedural-programming, procedural

I'm trying to make a maze generator in C#. None of the cells are ever set to CLOSED_TOP, CLOSED_BOTTOM, CLOSED_LEFT, CLOSED_RIGHT, or OPEN even when they do go down that new path.

I'm implementing a DFS algorithm for generating the maze:

1. Pick any random cell in the grid (In this implementation we use the upper left hand corner.)
2. Find a random neighboring cell that hasn't been visited yet.
3. If you find one, strip the wall between the current cell and the neighboring cell.
4. If you don't find one,  return to the previous cell.
5. Repeat steps 2 and 3  (or steps 2 and 4)  for every cell in the grid.

The problem comes in when I have returned to a previous cell (cell A), and continuing on to a new neighboring cell (cell B) that hasn't been visited yet. I know my code visits the new cell (cell B) and continues down that path, but it never marks the previous cell (cell A) as having three open sides.

I don't know what is wrong in my logic. I know that the entire grid gets populated. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MazeGenerator
{
    class MapGenerator
    {
        private Random random = new Random();

        public const int CLOSED = -1;

        public const int OPEN_TOP = 0;
        public const int OPEN_LEFT = 1;
        public const int OPEN_RIGHT = 2;
        public const int OPEN_BOTTOM = 3;

        public const int OPEN_TOP_LEFT = 4;
        public const int OPEN_TOP_RIGHT = 5;
        public const int OPEN_TOP_BOTTOM = 6;
        public const int OPEN_LEFT_RIGHT = 7;
        public const int OPEN_LEFT_BOTTOM = 8;
        public const int OPEN_RIGHT_BOTTOM = 9;

        public const int CLOSED_TOP = 10;
        public const int CLOSED_LEFT = 11;
        public const int CLOSED_RIGHT = 12;
        public const int CLOSED_BOTTOM = 13;

        public const int OPEN = 14;

        public int[] StartingPoint { get; }
        public int[] EndingPoint { get; }

        public int NumCols { get; set; }
        public int NumRows { get; set; }

        public int[,] MapGrid { get; }

        public MapGenerator(int numRows, int numCols)
        {
            NumCols = numCols;
            NumRows = numRows;

            MapGrid = new int[numRows, numCols];
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
                {
                    MapGrid[i,j] = CLOSED;
                }
            }

            StartingPoint = new int[] { 0, 0 };
            EndingPoint = new int[] { numRows - 1, numCols - 1 };

            GoDownPath(0, 0);
        }

        private void GoDownPath(int row, int col)
        {
            int cellState = MapGrid[row, col];

            while (NumberUnvisitedNeighbors(row, col) > 0)
            {
                // go down this path
                int nextCellWall = random.Next(0, 4);

                if (nextCellWall == 0)
                {
                    // go up
                    if (row > 0 && MapGrid[row - 1, col] == CLOSED)
                    {
                        switch (cellState)
                        {
                            case CLOSED:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_TOP;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_LEFT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_TOP_LEFT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_TOP_RIGHT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_TOP_BOTTOM;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_LEFT_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_BOTTOM;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_LEFT_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_RIGHT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_RIGHT_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_LEFT;
                                break;

                            case CLOSED_TOP:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;

                            default:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;
                        }

                        MapGrid[row - 1, col] = OPEN_BOTTOM;
                        GoDownPath(row - 1, col);
                    }
                } else if (nextCellWall == 1)
                {
                    // go down
                    if (row < NumRows - 1 && MapGrid[row + 1, col] == CLOSED)
                    {
                        switch (cellState)
                        {
                            case CLOSED:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_BOTTOM;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_TOP:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_TOP_BOTTOM;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_LEFT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_LEFT_BOTTOM;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_RIGHT_BOTTOM;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_TOP_LEFT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_RIGHT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_TOP_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_LEFT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_LEFT_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_TOP;
                                break;

                            case CLOSED_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;

                            default:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;
                        }

                        MapGrid[row + 1, col] = OPEN_TOP;
                        GoDownPath(row + 1, col);
                    }
                } else if (nextCellWall == 2)
                {
                    // go left
                    if (col > 0 && MapGrid[row, col - 1] == CLOSED)
                    {
                        switch (cellState)
                        {
                            case CLOSED:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_LEFT;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_TOP:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_TOP_LEFT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_LEFT_RIGHT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_LEFT_BOTTOM;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_TOP_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_BOTTOM;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_TOP_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_RIGHT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_RIGHT_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_TOP;
                                break;

                            case CLOSED_LEFT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;

                            default:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;
                        }

                        MapGrid[row, col - 1] = OPEN_RIGHT;
                        GoDownPath(row, col - 1);
                    }
                } else if (nextCellWall == 3)
                {
                    // go right
                    if (col < NumCols - 1 && MapGrid[row, col + 1] == CLOSED)
                    {
                        switch (cellState)
                        {
                            case CLOSED:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_RIGHT;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_TOP:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_TOP_RIGHT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_LEFT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_LEFT_RIGHT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN_RIGHT_BOTTOM;
                                break;

                            case OPEN_TOP_LEFT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_BOTTOM;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_TOP_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_LEFT;
                                break;
                            case OPEN_LEFT_BOTTOM:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = CLOSED_TOP;
                                break;

                            case CLOSED_RIGHT:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;

                            default:
                                MapGrid[row, col] = OPEN;
                                break;
                        }

                        MapGrid[row, col + 1] = OPEN_LEFT;
                        GoDownPath(row, col + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private int NumberUnvisitedNeighbors(int row, int col)
        {
            int numUnvisited = 0;

            if (row > 0 && MapGrid[row - 1, col] == CLOSED) numUnvisited++;
            if (row < NumRows - 1 && MapGrid[row + 1, col] == CLOSED) numUnvisited++;

            if (col > 0 && MapGrid[row, col - 1] == CLOSED) numUnvisited++;
            if (col < NumCols - 1 && MapGrid[row, col + 1] == CLOSED) numUnvisited++;

            return numUnvisited;
        }
    }
}
```